# How to deserialize a class to add info and then save

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine, filestream, binaryformatter

well i got a Serializable class which is being instantiated by another class but what i really want it to do is to first open the previously saved file and add a new element into a list but all i get is it just overwriting the previous information and then saving ( which i didn't want so i  changed from filemode.open to filemode.append ). So the deserialize class is called every time a game ends and i want this to open up a highscores and add a new element

**MY ISSUE STARTS IN Deserialize**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

public class LeaderboardManager : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler  {
    public GameObject leaderboardart;
    public static LeaderboardManager leaderboardmanager;
    void Awake() 
    {
        if (leaderboardmanager == null) 
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
            leaderboardmanager = this;
        } else if (leaderboardmanager!= this) {
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }

        if (File.Exists (Application.persistentDataPath + "/highscores.dat")) 
        {
            print("THE HIGHSCORES HAS BEEN CREATED");
        } 
        else 
        {
            PlayerData playdata = new PlayerData();
            FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath +"/highscores.dat");
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(file,playdata);
            file.Close();
        }
    }


    public void  Deserialize(int score) 
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/highscores.dat", FileMode.Append);
        PlayerData playdata = (PlayerData)bf.Deserialize(file);
        playdata.highscorelist.Add (score);
        bf.Serialize (file, playdata);
        file.Close ();
    }

    [Serializable]
    class PlayerData 
    {
        public List<int> highscorelist = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

error message

```
> ArgumentException: The stream doesn't support reading.
> System.IO.BinaryReader..ctor (System.IO.Stream input,
> System.Text.Encoding encoding) (at
> /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/BinaryReader.cs:68)
> System.IO.BinaryReader..ctor (System.IO.Stream input)
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.NoCheckDeserialize
> (System.IO.Stream serializationStream,
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.HeaderHandler handler) (at
> /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary/BinaryFormatter.cs:158)
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize
> (System.IO.Stream serializationStream) (at
```

Comment: Please spend a bit more time formatting your question next time. It was essentially un-readable before.

Comment: In addition to proper formatting, in the future also please remove irrelevant code from your example. It just confuses people, and you will get downvotes for your question.

Comment: sorry this was my second time asking a question. thanks for the advance

Comment: Hint: You can always edit your question so that anybody looking at this in the future doesn't have to read through 50% irrelevant code.

Answer (score 2):

You open the stream with the .Append flag, which is a write mode, so your BinaryFormatter rightly complains that it cannot read from a stream that was opened for writing only. Try this code. It first opens the highscore file in read mode, and then a second time in write mode to serialize all data, after updating the highscore in the class.

Do not use append. The binary format isn't just like a CSV format or so where you can append additional lines. You have to rewrite the entire file!

```
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        PlayerData playdata;

        using (FileStream file = File.Open("highscores.dat", FileMode.Open))
        {
            playerData = (PlayerData) bf.Deserialize(file);
        }

        playdata.highscorelist.Add(score);

        using (FileStream file = File.Open("highscores.dat", FileMode.Create))
        {
            bf.Serialize(file, playdata);
        }
```

Comment: thanks chris, i will try this when i get back from work.